# Indexing Metapackage wiki.ros.org

Tags: ros, documentation, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I read the tutorial on indexing of the packages (http://wiki.ros.org/rosdistro/Tutorials/Indexing%20Your%20ROS%20Repository%20for%20Documentation%20Generation)

If I release a metapackage do I have to create a wiki page for every package within by hand or will this be done automatically?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297077/indexing-metapackage-wiki.ros.org/) by [agutenkunst](https://answers.ros.org/users/30729/agutenkunst/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2018-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Wiki pages are never created automatically. You have to create them manually.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0